# The requested URL was rejected while trying to save the address book using special characters

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, ajax, php-7

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Go to the storefront
2. Log in as a customer
3. Go to My Account
4. Now go to Address Book and click on add new address button
5. Fill the address form ( add special characters in mandatory fields).
6. After filling address book, click on Save Address.

**Actual Result:**
The page is redirecting to the error page which displays the message as

> The requested URL was rejected.
>
> For additional information, please contact support  and provide this reference ID:

For reference check the screenshot attached below:
[image: The requested URL was rejected]

Comment: Can you please share details of your implemented code?

Comment: we didn't added any custom code.

Comment: Please also check your var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log files for errors.

Comment: I got the same error as above, the error only occurs on the server but on localhost it works normally. Is it because the firewall is blocking that link?

Comment: I get an error when editing a customer address. When I enter it into the system, when I save it, I get an error message "The requested URL has been rejected. For more information, please contact support and provide this reference ID: 170064036106aa7b54907f1469ee019". There was an error when running the test but localhost still works normally. Is there any solution? Thank you very much.